# This instance has too many database splits to complete the operation

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

Until now, even if 20 per database were created, no error was issued, but when I made suddenly more than 16 suddenly I got an error.

It is totally different from what is described in https://cloud.google.com/spanner/quotas. I do not understand the reason at all.

Comment: It came to occur before and after indexing the table. If you return it before putting index, I could create 20 instances.

I think that this is probably the cause, but is it written in the document?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear if you're talking about 20 and 16 secondary indexes and what was the type of the operation that you were trying to execute.

Just to be clear, splits are not indexes. Splits are not exposed to users in Cloud Spanner, see more details on the topic here:
https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/schema-and-data-model#database-splits

"Too many database splits" error indicates that you need more nodes to manage your dataset. A node may manage up to 2TB of data:
https://cloud.google.com/spanner/quotas#database_limits